# How to get refresh token from cache in msal?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I want to get refresh token in msal in java. In the documentation mentioned over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache) tells that the token can be obtained from the cache but I was not able to get any code which points out how to use the cache. Is there any code or documentation which I can refer to obtain the refresh token from the cache in msal in java.

Tried searching through docs but didn't find anything pertaining to storing tokens in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your question. Please find below the Java code sample for obtaining a refresh token from the cache using MSAL. You can use this code to retrieve a refresh token for a specific user account and set of scopes.

Before executing the sample code you need to update the variables with your own values.

Also note that you must have previously acquired a token for the specified scope and user account in order for the token to be stored in the cache. If the token is not present in the cache, the `acquireTokenSilently` method will throw an exception and you will need to acquire a new token using the `acquireToken` method.

```
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class MsalCacheDemoExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up the public client application
        String clientId = "<your-client-id>";
        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>";
        PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId)
                .authority(authority)
                .build();

        // Get the user Account details
        String username = "<your-username>";
        UserAccount account = UserAccount.builder()
                .username(username)
                .build();

        // Set up the silent parameters. Ensure you  entered the right scopes
        SilentParameters parameters = SilentParameters.builder(scopes, account).build();

        // Acquire the token silently
        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = pca.acquireTokenSilently(parameters);

        //IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
        
        // Handle the result
        future.handle((result, throwable) -> {
            if (throwable != null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to acquire token silently: " + throwable.getMessage());
            } else {
                String refreshToken = result.refreshToken();
                System.out.println("Refresh token: " + refreshToken);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

More Information about acquiring token silently from the cache maintained by MSAL is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache).

Reference for PublicClientApplication class is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication?view=azure-java-stable).

Comment: I tried the above example but result has no such method known as `refreshToken()`. The `refreshToken()` is not available in `IAuthenticationResult` interface but is available in the `AuthenticationResult` class which is not accessible as it a package private class.

Is there any other alternative to getting the refresh token ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please let me know if the 2 below sample code helps:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/msal4j-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/RefreshTokenRequest.java

AND

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/msal4j-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/RefreshTokenCacheEntity.java